# Pop instance of a class from list

Tags: python, list

I would like to remove the first instance of `classB` from my list `l` without knowing the index. I know that `list.pop()` takes indices, so I would first need to get the index of the instance in the list. Basically something along these lines:

```
class classA:
    pass

class classB:
    pass

A1 = classA()
A2 = classA()
B = classB()
l = [A1, A2, B]

x = l.pop(l.index(classB))
```

with `x` now being `B`, and `l` now looking like this:

```
l = [A1, A2]
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please read the description of `index`; you have to give it the *value* to find, not the type.  index(B) should do what you want.

Comment: You want to remove the first instance of classB? Or a specific instance of classB (assuming multiple could be in the list)?

Comment: I want the first instance of classB (there will only be one). I also didn't specify my question enough: I don't know the name of classB, so index(B) won't work.  Thankfully a bunch of people already replied and I will try out their answers tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write a for-loop:

```
for idx, obj in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(obj, classB):
        x = l.pop(idx)
        break
else:
    raise ValueError("no instance of classB in list")
```

If you will use this multiple times, wrap it up in a function. The logic is non-trivial, so resist the temptation to one-liner it.

Answer (score 2):

Find the index of the first element of your class with a generator expression + `next`. The generator expression lazily evaluates entries until it finds one that's an instance of `classB`, then yields the index. `next` pulls that first index produced and then stops asking for anything else (so you don't scan the whole `list` when you find the instance you want early):

```
# Raises StopIteration if no classB
bidx = next(i for i, x in enumerate(l) if isinstance(x, classB))
```

then `pop` it off:

```
x = l.pop(bidx)
```

You can merge the two to get:

```
x = l.pop(next(i for i, x in enumerate(l) if isinstance(x, classB)))
```

though that's a little dense for a single line to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
index_of_first_B = next(i for i, value in enumerate(list) if isinstance(value, B))
```

This throws an exception if there is no such B.  If you don't want this treated as an exception:

```
index_of_first_B = next((i for i, value in enumerate(list) if isinstance(value, B)), None)
```

to get it to return None.  Note you need extra parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

```
class classA:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
class classB:
   def __init__(self):
      pass

A1 = classA()
A2 = classA()
B = classB()
l = [A1, A2, B]
print(l)

# # in your way but only if you know the name of the item
# x = l.pop(l.index(B))
# print(l)

# if you don't know the name [Wrong]
l1 = [x for x in l if type(x) is not classB]
print(l1)
```

```
# [Correct]
# if you don't know the name
for idx, obj in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(obj, classB):
        x = l.pop(idx)
```

Comment: This doesn't alter the original list which is what the OP desires.  Instead, this just creates a new list.  Also, it doesn't work if `l` contains an element from a subclass of `classB`.

Comment: I see, yeah, `isinstance` is better if we also want to remove subclasses of `classB`